# C++ Trouble with operators ()

Tags: c++, arduino

Theres problem with Arduino scetch
Its part of code:

```
![void verifica(){
    msg=msg.substring(1,13);
    if(ID.indexOf(msg)>=0) Serial.println("Access granted.");
    {
      digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
      delay(2000);
      digitalWrite(10, LOW);
    }
    else Serial.println("Access denied.");
    {
      digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
      delay(2000);
      digitalWrite(9, LOW);
    }
}
```

So i got trouble with compiling, theres looks like no fail. Im sorry, and yeah, im n00b =(
http://s019.radikal.ru/i608/1501/5e/db7c7db4380b.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got an `else` with no attached `if`.

Presumably, the `println` are supposed to be inside the following block, rather than being the entire body of the `if` statement:

```
if(ID.indexOf(msg)>=0)
{
  Serial.println("Access granted.");  // <<< inside if body
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(10, LOW);
}
else
{
  Serial.println("Access denied.");   // <<< inside else body
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);
}
```